# Adding and taking columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum

I am using Microsoft Access. I am wondering is it possible to add the column *dislikes* and take it away from the total of the column *likes* but at the same time I want it to group by *car_id* which equals to a parameter, so whatever the user types in as the parameter it groups by that.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT SUM(Likes.like - Likes.dislike) AS AllLikes
FROM Likes
GROUP BY car_id
WHERE car_id = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause should be before the `GROUP BY`. Access will object when it finds them in the opposite order.

```sql
SELECT Likes.car_id, SUM(Likes.like - Likes.dislike) AS AllLikes
FROM Likes
WHERE Likes.car_id = [which car_id?]
GROUP BY Likes.car_id;
```

However, since you want to filter the intermediate result set for a single *car_id*, I don't think you even need a `GROUP BY`.

```sql
SELECT SUM(Likes.like - Likes.dislike) AS AllLikes
FROM Likes
WHERE Likes.car_id = [which car_id?];
```

Comment: It works the 2nd way, however with this line `WHERE Likes.car_id = ?` it gives an error "no value given for one or more required parameters" even though it had never prompted me to type in the value for the parameter?

Comment: What happens if you enclose the question mark in square brackets like this ... `WHERE Likes.car_id = [?]`